# existe alguna alternativa a sox(sound exchange) para windows

Tags: python

Estoy intentando hacer uso de este script en python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


"""PyVoiceChanger."""


import sys
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import call
from time import sleep

from PyQt5.QtCore import QProcess, Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtGui import QColor, QCursor, QIcon
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDial, QGraphicsDropShadowEffect,
                             QGroupBox, QLabel, QMainWindow, QMenu,
                             QShortcut, QSystemTrayIcon, QVBoxLayout)

from anglerfish import (check_encoding, make_logger, make_post_exec_msg,
                        set_process_name, set_single_instance,
                        set_desktop_launcher)


__version__ = '1.0.0'
__license__ = ' GPLv3+ LGPLv3+ '
__author__ = ' juancarlos '
__email__ = ' juancarlospaco@gmail.com '
__url__ = 'https://github.com/juancarlospaco/pyvoicechanger#pyvoicechanger'
start_time = datetime.now()
desktop_file_content = """
[Desktop Entry]
Comment=Voice Changer App.
Exec=chrt --idle 0 pyvoicechanger.py
GenericName=Voice Changer App.
Icon=audio-input-microphone
Name=PyVoiceChanger
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility
X-DBUS-ServiceName=pyvoicechanger
X-KDE-StartupNotify=true
"""


###############################################################################


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    """Voice Changer main window."""

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.statusBar().showMessage("Move Dial to Deform Microphone Voice !.")
        self.setWindowTitle(__doc__)
        self.setMinimumSize(240, 240)
        self.setMaximumSize(480, 480)
        self.resize(self.minimumSize())
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("audio-input-microphone"))
        self.tray = QSystemTrayIcon(self)
        self.center()
        QShortcut("Ctrl+q", self, activated=lambda: self.close())
        self.menuBar().addMenu("&File").addAction("Quit", lambda: exit())
        self.menuBar().addMenu("Sound").addAction(
            "STOP !", lambda: call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox']))
        windowMenu = self.menuBar().addMenu("&Window")
        windowMenu.addAction("Hide", lambda: self.hide())
        windowMenu.addAction("Minimize", lambda: self.showMinimized())
        windowMenu.addAction("Maximize", lambda: self.showMaximized())
        windowMenu.addAction("Restore", lambda: self.showNormal())
        windowMenu.addAction("FullScreen", lambda: self.showFullScreen())
        windowMenu.addAction("Center", lambda: self.center())
        windowMenu.addAction("Top-Left", lambda: self.move(0, 0))
        windowMenu.addAction("To Mouse", lambda: self.move_to_mouse_position())
        # widgets
        group0 = QGroupBox("Voice Deformation")
        self.setCentralWidget(group0)
        self.process = QProcess(self)
        self.process.error.connect(
            lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage("Info: Process Killed", 5000))
        self.control = QDial()
        self.control.setRange(-10, 20)
        self.control.setSingleStep(5)
        self.control.setValue(0)
        self.control.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor))
        self.control.sliderPressed.connect(
            lambda: self.control.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.ClosedHandCursor)))
        self.control.sliderReleased.connect(
            lambda: self.control.setCursor(QCursor(Qt.OpenHandCursor)))
        self.control.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.control.setToolTip("<b>" + str(self.control.value())))
        self.control.valueChanged.connect(
            lambda: self.statusBar().showMessage(
                "Voice deformation: " + str(self.control.value()), 5000))
        self.control.valueChanged.connect(self.run)
        self.control.valueChanged.connect(lambda: self.process.kill())
        # Graphic effect
        self.glow = QGraphicsDropShadowEffect(self)
        self.glow.setOffset(0)
        self.glow.setBlurRadius(99)
        self.glow.setColor(QColor(99, 255, 255))
        self.control.setGraphicsEffect(self.glow)
        self.glow.setEnabled(False)
        # Timer to start
        self.slider_timer = QTimer(self)
        self.slider_timer.setSingleShot(True)
        self.slider_timer.timeout.connect(self.on_slider_timer_timeout)
        # an icon and set focus
        QLabel(self.control).setPixmap(
            QIcon.fromTheme("audio-input-microphone").pixmap(32))
        self.control.setFocus()
        QVBoxLayout(group0).addWidget(self.control)
        self.menu = QMenu(__doc__)
        self.menu.addAction(__doc__).setDisabled(True)
        self.menu.setIcon(self.windowIcon())
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(
            "Show / Hide",
            lambda: self.hide() if self.isVisible() else self.showNormal())
        self.menu.addAction("STOP !", lambda: call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox']))
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction("Quit", lambda: exit())
        self.tray.setContextMenu(self.menu)
        self.make_trayicon()

    def run(self):
        """Run/Stop the QTimer."""
        if self.slider_timer.isActive():
            self.slider_timer.stop()
        self.glow.setEnabled(True)
        call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox'])
        self.slider_timer.start(3000)

    def on_slider_timer_timeout(self):
        """Run subprocess to deform voice."""
        self.glow.setEnabled(False)
        value = int(self.control.value()) * 100
        cmd = 'play -q -V0 "|rec -q -V0 -n -d -R riaa bend pitch {0} "'
        command = cmd.format(int(value))
        log.debug("Voice Deformation Value: {0}".format(value))
        log.debug("Voice Deformation Command: {0}".format(command))
        self.process.start(command)
        if self.isVisible():
            self.statusBar().showMessage("Minimizing to System TrayIcon", 3000)
            log.debug("Minimizing Main Window to System TrayIcon now...")
            sleep(3)
            self.hide()

    def center(self):
        """Center Window on the Current Screen,with Multi-Monitor support."""
        window_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        mousepointer_position = QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos()
        screen = QApplication.desktop().screenNumber(mousepointer_position)
        centerPoint = QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry(screen).center()
        window_geometry.moveCenter(centerPoint)
        self.move(window_geometry.topLeft())

    def move_to_mouse_position(self):
        """Center the Window on the Current Mouse position."""
        window_geometry = self.frameGeometry()
        window_geometry.moveCenter(QApplication.desktop().cursor().pos())
        self.move(window_geometry.topLeft())

    def make_trayicon(self):
        """Make a Tray Icon."""
        if self.windowIcon() and __doc__:
            self.tray.setIcon(self.windowIcon())
            self.tray.setToolTip(__doc__)
            self.tray.activated.connect(
                lambda: self.hide() if self.isVisible()
                else self.showNormal())
            return self.tray.show()


###############################################################################


def main():
    """Main Loop."""
    global log
    log = make_logger("pyvoicechanger")
    log.debug(__doc__ + __version__ + __url__)
    check_encoding()
    set_process_name("pyvoicechanger")
    set_single_instance("pyvoicechanger")
    set_desktop_launcher("pyvoicechanger", desktop_file_content)
    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    application.setApplicationName("pyvoicechanger")
    application.setOrganizationName("pyvoicechanger")
    application.setOrganizationDomain("pyvoicechanger")
    application.setWindowIcon(QIcon.fromTheme("audio-input-microphone"))
    application.aboutToQuit.connect(lambda: call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox']))
    mainwindow = MainWindow()
    mainwindow.show()
    make_post_exec_msg(start_time)
    sys.exit(application.exec_())


if __name__ in '__main__':
    main()
```

El problema es que en la opción

```
cmd = 'play -q -V0 "|rec -q -V0 -n -d -R riaa bend pitch {0} "'
```

El parámetro play no esta disponible en windows y rec no existe  tampoco por lo que hago uso del siguiente comando

```
sox -V0 -d raw.wav
```

Pero lo que quiero es que me grabe y me reproduzca. También tengo otro error que cuando hago esto:

```
call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox'])
```

Me pone siempre:

> Error process not found

Cuando el proceso si esta creado correctamente y deberia ser capaz de identificarlo y cerrarlo.

Al final quería un script en python que hará algo parecido a lo que hicieron en este video con fines de estudio:
[objetivo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rJZT6u5SxX0)

Tal vez como podeis comprobar funciona perfectamente en windows, pero de momento no consigo por lo que pregunto alguien me podría indicar cual es la mejor opcion para windows para poder grabar y reproducir efectos de voz usando python.

Comment: Sir he estado mirando el tema un poco, el problema con taskill se debe a que por defecto retorna un error si el proceso no es encontrado. Se soluciona ´facil, o bien deshabilitas el uso de shell en la llamada a call : `call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox'], shell = False` o te las arreglas para que no envie el error usando shell, por ejemplo: `call(['START', 'taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox'], shell = True)`.Tengo tu programa funcionando para la grabación, tambien puedo reproducir un archivo en disco, el problema ahora es unir ambas cosas, ¿Se supone que debe reproducir al mismo tiempo que graba?

Comment: Una observación, el proceso es `sox.exe`, el comando para matar el proceso debe ser : `call(['taskkill', '/F', '/IM', 'sox.exe'], shell = False)`. Es lo que estoy usando, funciona sin problemas por esta parte. Mata el proceso cuando existe y se queda calladito cuando no existe :)

Comment: claro era eso lo que intentaba y exacto lo que intentaba era que grabe y reproduzca los sonidos.